# Who is the consumer in a POST scenario?

Tags: pact

I have read that on Pact, the consumer is the one initiating the request. I have a service (let's call it A) that is used to draw pictures that will then be submitted (via POST) to a service (let's call it B) that will process those inputs and generate albums.

My question is: If the service B is the expert on knowing which kind of inputs and in which format should receive in order to create albums, how come is service A the consumer and therefore the one that will be writing the contract? Shouldn't it be the service B that specifies what kind of data should be receiving?

Answer (score 0):

From [1]:

> A component that initiates a HTTP request to another component (the service Provider). Note that this does not depend on the way the data flows - whether it is a GET or a PUT / POST / PATCH, the Consumer is the initiator of the HTTP request.

But I think your question is really asking about *consumer driven contract testing* [2]. You're conflating who is building the service with expertise / understanding of the requirements for its existence. The Consumer knows what it needs from the service, and the Provider knows how to implement it.

Consumer driven contracts reverses the typical API design process of creating an API first and then consumers coming along to use it. First, the consumer specifies what it requires, publishes the expectations as a contract and the Provider then implements it.

Pact generally assumes this mode, but it's not strictly necessary (i.e. the Provider API can exist in advance).

[1] https://docs.pact.io/documentation/how_does_pact_work.html
[2] https://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html